# как выровнять табличку для разных экранов

Tags: html, css

добрый день. на сайте[image: введите сюда описание изображения] есть табличка с тремя . при уменьшении разрешения экрана табличка заплывает за грани, как показано на картинке. как это можно исправить???

Comment: вот ссылка на сайт ---http://geosky.ge

Comment: 1. Не видно таблички. 2. В оригинале вроде слайд-шоу было. 3. Чтобы элементы были адаптивными, надо использовать media queries в CSS и там все регулировать как надо.

Comment: В этом элементе есть блок `<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 2960px; left: 0px;...` Поэтому и выступает...

Comment: Какая табличка? За какие грани?

Comment: вот те три картинки которые изображении. а вот третья заходит за грань на маленьких экранах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 32%;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/1024/768">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/1024/769">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/1024/767">
  </div>
</div>
```